# Отправка информации в сервлет из выпадающего списка select

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet, jstl

Добрый день. Есть контроллер из которого на страницу передаются Enum для выпадающего списка

```
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public String registration(Model model){
ArrayList<CourseLocation> location = new ArrayList<CourseLocation>();
    for(CourseLocation loc : CourseLocation.values()) {
        location.add(loc);
        }
   model.addAttribute("locat", location);
        return "registration";
}
```

На странице информация вставляется циклом,

```
   LocationBtn:<br/>
                <select class="selectpicker" >
                <c:forEach items="${location}" var="location">
                 <option value ="${location.toString()}">${location.toString()}</option>
                </c:forEach>
                 </select><br/>
```

Это добро находится в форме с другими input type="text" и по кнопке передается в другой контроллер для создания пользователя. Как мне в него передать из выпадающего списка нужный enum?

```
      @RequestParam(required = false) CourseLocation location,
```

Возможно я смогу передать на страницу из первого контроллера не ArrayList а сам Enum? Но у меня не получилось.

Я пробовал передать во второй контроллер
@RequestParam(required = false) CourseLocation location.toString()
но компилятор не порадовался такому решению.

Возможно есть вариант переопределения option value ="${loc}" и где то присвоить ${loc=location.toString()}?

Кто то сталкивался с такой задачей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно передать enum. Сначала надо импортировать его на страницу:

```
<%@page import="my.package.CourseLocation"%>
```

Потом написать:

```
<c:forEach items="<%=CourseLocation.values()%>" var="location">
    <option value ="${location.name()}">${location.toString()}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

(Сам не проверял. В интернете нашёл)

Важно чтобы `value = location.name()`
`toString()` можно переопределить, а `name()` всегда одно и тоже. Это название элемента. Элемент можно потом восстановить с помощью `valueOf(String name)`.

```
@RequestParam(required = false) String locationName,
...
CourseLocation location = CourseLocation.valueOf(locationName);
```

Spring пытаетесь применить? Стоило бы добавить тег spring.
И стоит посмотреть - может ли спринг чем помочь?
Вдруг и `@RequestParam(required = false) CourseLocation location,` заработает, когда `value=location.name()`. Мало ли что Вы там в `toString` написали, вот стандартный механизм восстановления enum-а и не сработал.

Ну и ещё есть вариант с использованием `ordinal()`. Но с текстовыми названиями как-то нагляднее и поэтому проще. Сразу видно что где.

Кстати сам никогда не переопределяю toString для enum. Ведь в enum можно добавлять свои методы и поля. Например какой-нибудь getLabel()

```
<option value ="${location.name()}">${location.label}</option>
```

Comment: Спасибо, принимаю ваш ответ, тем более что вы на него ответили  и в моем продублированном через день вопросе, который был уже более структурированным. Добавлю что, то что вы нашли в интернете работает, и его даже можно упростить. Единственное что @RequestParam(required = false) CourseLocation location не заработает когда value=location.name(), страница при загрузке ругнется что в классе Course location нет метода .name(), но этого и ненужно. Можно передать value=location.

Answer (score 0):

Как изменился код для решения задачи:

Я ничего не посылаю из первого сервлета

```
 @RequestMapping("/registration")
 public String registration(){
 return "registration";
 }
```

Enum передаю сразу на страницу

```
 HEAD  <%@ page import="enum" %> /HEAD
```

Цикл для выпадающего списка на странице выглядит так

```
 <select class="selectpicker" id ="loc" name ="loc">
 <c:forEach items="<%=CourseLocation.values()%>" var="location">
 <option value = "${location}">${location}</option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

В принимающем значение сервлете я ловлю

```
 @RequestParam(required = false) CourseLocation loc
```

где loc это name="" у тега Select, так как

Select сам определяет какой option был выбран на странице без дополнительных манипуляций. Он забирает значение value="val" у выбранного option

Для того чтобы Select отправил значение на сервер, мы должны дать ему параметр name="n". На сервере в сервлете как раз ловим "n" который хранит в себе "val" выбранного пункта выпадающего меню.